# Delete records from MySQL database based on sum of points

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have in the database rewards points table :

```
customer_reward_id  customer_id      order_id        points
1                        1               3             20
2                        1               4             40
3                        1               5             30
4                        1               6             30
5                        1               7             40
```

Collecting 100 points (sum) and delete from table

> where customer_id =1 order by customer_reward_id ASC

any idea?

Comment: Your question is not clear..`i want to sum and delete 100 points only` What this means??

Comment: I want to sum and delete 100 points only ??? What you mean by this?

Comment: select 100 points only and delete ! why not clear ?

Comment: Probably you want to add and delete 100 points? Well AND points < 100 or you want delete command?

Comment: DELETE from rewards_points WHERE points = 100 
What do you want to add?

Comment: Collecting 100 points and deleted where customer_id =1 order by customer_reward_id ASC

Comment: Deleting records from the table is not the right option to reduce the reward points. Instead add -100 rewards to the same customer and then sum all the points for that customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real applications, we do not delete the records to deduct the points from the customers. Because every record with the orders are required for reporting and management purposes. Instead the best way to deduct 100 points from the customer is to add the points with a negative sign and then sum up all the points so that you'll get the final value.

For example do the following:

Insert new record with negative value.

```
insert into reward_points (customer_id,order_id,points) values (1,8,-100);
```

Then sum the total value as below.

```
select sum(points) as total_rewards where customer_id=1;
```

This way you'll keep all the records of the previous orders as well as reduce the rewards too.

Hope this helps for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about deleting record for customer who are having 100 points or more (summed up). Here is the query:

```
delete from rewards_points 
where customer_id in (
    SELECT customer_id 
    FROM (select * from `rewards_points`) dummy
    group by customer_id
    having sum(points)>=100);
```

**Note:** In MySQL you can't specify same table in `from` clause directly, in which you are performing delete/update operation. So, In this answer I've added extra sub-query and given alias `dummy`

Comment: It will delete customer points if its having>=100 points. From your question that is what i understood. If you want to reduce few points for customer then you'l need to add another records with -ve points. Tell me what exactly you need?

Comment: i want to delete only 100 points.
 I understand the solution now  insert -100 points